# Ruby gem to drag/drop images onto web page

Tags: ruby, image-processing, drag-and-drop

I'm interested in making a web page where users can drop images onto the page, and then a Ruby script will run using the dropped image.

What gems are available to help with handling this behavior?

Comment: i think your question fits best in a forum, but anyway.  
take a look at this:  
[rubytoolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/image_processing)

Comment: look into Jquery: http://www.spritle.com/blogs/2010/03/27/drag-n-drop-web-components-using-jquery-rails/